# БД с разными источниками для хранимых данных

Tags: база-данных, проектирование, идентификация

Проектируется приложение с использованием БД (SQLite). Предполагается, что пользователь может сущности задать иконку из предустановленных или загрузить свою локальную, а соответственно в БД для этой сущности нужно сохранить значение иконки. Вся сложность в том, что иконка хранится в разных местах (либо ресурсы приложения, либо локально).

Придумал несколько решений:

1. Есть таблица entities и icons. У entities fk на icons. В icons храним пути до иконки и признак is_local (выбираем как грузить иконку).

а) Используем обычный id, тогда будут трудности при расширении массива встроенных иконок. Можно, конечно, зарезервировать некоторый пул id под встроенные (1000, например), но похоже на костыль.

б) Используем uuid, где для новых встроенных иконок генерируем новый и никогда не забываем. Ненадёжно, в коде присутствуют длинные константы, которые нельзя повреждать.

**Общий недостаток:** храним пути до внутренних ресурсов в БД предназначенной для данных пользователя.

2. Тоже самое, но без FK. Тогда нет необходимости хранить в БД данные о ресурсах. Можно использовать int для встроенных, uuid для локальных.

**Недостаток:** нет FK.

3. В принципе, частный случай #2, который повторяет #1, но выделить решил отдельно. Для предустановленных иконок используем отрицательные ID, а для пользовательских (в отдельной таблице) - положительные.

**Недостатки:** отрицательный ID (выглядит плохо), нет FK.

4. Храним данные об иконках сразу в entities

**Недостаток:** нарушаем нормализацию, может быть много повторов одних и тех же длинных TEXT.

5. Есть два вида icon_id у сущности. Один из них NULL, другой NOT NULL (проверяем триггером). FK на таблицу с данными о пользовательских иконок, а id встроенных мы знаем в самом приложении.

**Недостаток:** сложно для понимания, лишние столбцы.

Какое из решений обычно применяется в подобных ситуациях? Склоняюсь к #3 или #5. Может есть другие, которые я упустил?

Answer (score 0):

Вы никогда не пользовались линуксом?

Предлагаю вариант #6.
Опереться на опыт организации иконок у FreeDesktop.

[Icon Theme Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html)

[Icon Naming Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html)

Хранить можно как в ФС, так и в БД.

Использовать FK не стоит. Всегда надо предусматривать такой вариант событий, что под какую-то новую фичу или приложение не найдется нужно иконки. Структура БД не должна мешать прогрессу.

Именовать иконки и обращаться к ним лучше всего по тем же принципам, как именование переменных. Номера иконок - это жесть. Вы же не хотели бы разбираться в коде, где переменные имели бы вместо названий номера!

Если иконок много тысяч, лучше собрать их в один архив. Только архив **без сжатия** и с **индексированным списком файлов**. Это чтобы иконками можно было пользоваться налету не распаковывая архив целиком.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то применительно к моему случаю: 1. В entites я храню только имя иконки. 2. При загрузке я читаю это имя и ищу в двух предустановленных местах, по приоритету. Если иконка найдена в первом месте, то её устанавливаю. Если не найдена, ухожу на поиск в другом месте. Примерно так?

Comment: Мне все же сложно рассуждать со стороны вашей задачи. Вам там известно куда больше чем мне. Ну а со стороны FreeDesktop могу вкратце рассказать. Путь до файлов иконок /usr/share/icons/${имя_темы}/${размер}/${функция}/имя_иконки.{png,svg}. Стоит отметить тот факт, что у многих тем прописаны одна, две и иногда даже три fallback-темы как зависимости. Это получается что-то вроде наследования в ООП. Если в теме нет какой-то иконки она ищется и берётся из fallback-тем. Примечательно, что иконки разных размеров, интересный алгоритм подбора размера перед растягиванием векторной версии.

Comment: Все можно посмотреть на примерах: 
стандартной темы GTK https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/adwaita-icon-theme/ и кастомной https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/arc-icon-theme/ . По этим ссылкам на странице можно открыть список файлов в пакете. нажав на ссылку *View the file list*. И их можно скачать по ссылке *Download From Mirror* в меню справа. Список остальных тем тут: https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?sort=&q=icon-theme&maintainer=&flagged=
 . Архив распаковывается командой tar -I zstd -xvf archive.tar.zst . Алгоритм сжатия тут https://github.com/facebook/zstd .

Comment: В линуксах обычно три уровня конфигов, библиотек, прочих данных: 1) файлы дистрибутива /usr/{bin,sbin,lib,libexec,share} ; 2) локальные файлы /usr/local/{bin,sbin,lib,libexec,share} (то есть модифицированные файлы дистрибутивов, которые распространяются на всех пользователей; 3) пользовательские папки $HOME/.local (личные предпочтения пользователя). Они могут перегружать друг-друга. Если, например, пак иконок будет с одинаковым названием во всех трех местах, высший приоритет у пользовательских тем иконок, потом локальный, потом дистрибутивный.

Comment: Да, это несколько неподходящий для моей задачи алгоритм. У меня есть некоторая сущность с иконкой. Иконка может быть: 1) Загружена из ресурсов приложения (одним методом); 2) Иконка может быть пользовательской и загружаться из файловой системы (совершенно другим методом). Пользовательская иконка не изменяет существующую стандартную, а дополняет уже существующий набор возможных иконок. Приложением загружается сущность и у неё есть id иконки. Приложение также должно понять тип иконки. В зависимости от него уходит на один или второй метод загрузки.

Comment: Я решил остановится на том, что ID стандартных иконок будут отрицательными. Плюсы: 1) Не надо хранить в БД информации о стандартных иконках. 2) INTEGER для хранения компактнее TEXT. Работает так: пользователь добавляет свою иконку, название файла иконки сохраняется в отдельной таблице icons и там же у иконки назначается секвенцией ID. Сущности проставляется уже не полный путь до иконки, а только ID. У разных сущностей может быть одинаковая иконка.